# Wait for Mouse Event

Tags: java, mouseevent, jbutton, mouselistener

I am building a game of top trumps and I need my program to pause execution until a JButton is clicked. I have done a google search and there does not seem to be any wait for mouse event option in Java. I have created an alternative solution but I suspect it is eating up memory. This is working for and returns what I need. Is this potentially eating up memory? is there a more efficient solution to this? (I added a method that pauses execution for 1 second and this does seem to slow the amount of memory being used)

Update: I am creating a game of trumps and when my card information is printed the game needs me to pick a skill. I.E There is 5 buttons to choose from that return a string value;

```
public String getPick() {
    pick = getMouseClick();
    System.out.println(pick);
    return pick;
}

private String getMouseClick() {
    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {             
         public void mouseClicked(String e) { 
            setPick(e);
         } 
      });   

return pick;
```

Comment: _Is this potentially eating up memory?_ **Definitely**. This way you are creating millions of new `MouseAdapter` objects and adding them as mouse listeners, this is not what you want to do.

Comment: You don't wait for Mouse Event - Mouse Event is waiting for you...

Comment: The program will continue running without a pick and just crash. The paceTheGame method seems to really help with the memory issue, but i should probably create the mouseAdaptor outside of the while loop

Comment: Instead of waiting for a button press to occur, you should design your game such that nothing new is occurring and a button press starts a new event / triggers some actions. This way you're not waiting for a button press and eating up memory.

Comment: @GaryKelly You need to rework this. mouse events are ***events***, you don't wait for them, you subscribe and get notified when they happen. If you have to wait for them, you are going in the wrong direction.

Comment: @BackSlash3 Ok thanks, I'll go back to the drawing board on this one and come up with a different way